# MySQL takes An exclusive (X) lock to a JOINed table with UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I'm looking for the cause of `(1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')` on MySQL InnoDB. Is there a possibility of Deadlock??

```
1: insert into TABLE_A ... on duplicate key update where id = N
2: update TABLE_B b set b.name = a.name left join TABLE_A a where a.id = N
```

My Python app sends the queries 100,000 times continuously. Succeeds 99%, but some get the deadlock.

My hypothesis:

`Query [2]` arrives at the MySQL server before `Query [1]`.

Adding sleep(1) between them solved the issue. Now I need to learn the cause.
If my hypothesis is correct, the following occurs:

a. `[2]` acquires `s-lock` with `left join`

b. `[1]` waits for acquiring `x-lock` because `s-lock of [2]` blocks it

c. `[2]` is locked to wait for `x-lock`(I don't understand why it happens)

Can you explain the deadlock cause, please?

---

The MySQL is:

```
Server version: 8.0.19 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

Query 1 & 2 are in the same connection. I use python MySQLdb with `autocommit=True`

---

Whole test code:

```
# preparation
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_a` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_a` int NOT NULL,
  `name_b` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

insert into A (name_a) values ('a1');
insert into B (id_a, name_b) values (1, 'b1');

# verify name_a = a1 and name_b = b1
select * from A a left join B b on b.id_a = a.id;

# Query 1
insert into A (id, name_a) values (1, 'new') on duplicate key update id = 1, name_a = 'new';

# Query 2
update B b left join A a on b.id_a = a.id
set b.name_b = a.name_a
where b.id_a = 1;

# verify name_a and name_b has 'new'
select * from A a left join B b on b.id_a = a.id;
```

Comment: are [1] and [2] in the same connection & transaction?  or not?  is the `id = N` in the update TABLE_B.id?  or TABLE_A?

Comment: please do provide full details (create table & insert of sample data and the actual update and insert queries you are doing) enough to duplicate the problem easily

Comment: Edited the question. specify [2], they are in the same connection with `autocommit=True`. I add the whole query, wait a minute

Comment: Added the whole code. It should use a Foreign key but not used yet.

Comment: if they are in the same connection but autocommitting, so not in the same transaction, there's no way they are affecting each other.  or do you mean one process's [2] is running at the same time as another process's [1]?

Comment: Please run `show engine innodb status` and add the "latest detected deadlock" section to your question.